# Writing 3 numbers in consecutive order C++

Tags: c++

Iam studying Bjarne Stroustrups book. Iam currently on chapter 3 and i need to create a program where the user inputs 3 numbers and the program should output them in consecutive order. I have searched the site and others have posted the same exercise but i tried doing it my way and it seems that there is a logical problem because the IDE is not finding any problem with my source code. I have my suspitions though. Here is the source code.

```
  #include "../../../std_lib_facilities.h"
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter three values\n";
    cout << "Enter the first value\n";
    int val1 = 0;
    int high = 00;
    int low = 000;
    cin >> val1;
    cout << "Enter the second value\n";
    int val2 = 0;
    cin >> val2;
    if (val1 >= val2)
        high = val1;
        low = val2;
    if (val1 <= val2)
        high = val2;
        low = val1;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the third value\n";
    int val3 = 0;
    if (val3 >= high)
        cout << low << " " << high << " " << val3;
    if (val3 <= low)
        cout << val3 << " " << low << " " << high;
    if (low < val3 < high)
        cout << low << " " << val3 << " " << high;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

When i start the program everything goes fine till i enter the second number. At that instance the program outputs 4 values and doent move on to the third command. Its weird i dont know but it must be something with the assignment of int low , high ,val1 and val2. Here is sample output:

```
Enter three values
Enter the first value
5
Enter the second value
4

Enter the third value
0 5 55 0 5
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: forgive the first cout. I forgot to fix it

Comment: How many `cin` calls are you making?

Comment: Also, `int high = 00` doesn't make sense. It's just zero.

Comment: And put curly braces around your if statements.

Comment: oh...its fixed. i was so sure it was right i didnt look at my code i went straight on thinking my reasoning must have been wrong

Comment: It's still wrong until you add curly braces. Without braces, only the first line after an `if` is evaluated. In your code, `low` will always be `val1`. It's good practice to always put braces around if/while/for statements even if they're only one line.

Comment: i did put curly braces. it seems that the program does fine except when the second value is lower than the first

Comment: Re-read my first comment. You have two `cin` statements in the code you've provided.

Comment: @Paulkalo you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35997122/edit) your question to update your code. It's fine now, because there are no answers, but once answers start popping up please be modest about the changes you make, since you might invalidate them.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a couple of problems.

```
int high = 00;
```

This isn't *wrong*, but you are inadvertantly using a language feature you may not understand.  When you precede a number with `0`, the compiler understands that to mean that your number is an octal value.  `00` happens to be the same as `0`, but in general it's best to write such lines as `int high = 0;`, or even better just `int high;`

---

```
if (val1 >= val2)
    high = val1;
    low = val2;
```

`high = val1;` is in the statement of the if, but `low = val2;` is not.  You clearly intended

```
if (val1 >= val2)
{
    high = val1;
    low = val2;
}
```

Most code review guidelines suggest using `{` and `}` for ALL if/while/for statements (including 1-line statements!) because it's such an insidious error.

---

```
cout << "Enter the third value\n";
int val3 = 0;
if (val3 >= high)
```

At no point do you actually read in the third value.  This is why the program continues to completion after entering the second value.  You probably intended...

```
cout << "Enter the third value\n";
int val3 = 0;
cin >> val3;
if (val3 >= high)
```

---

**Overall Structure**

There is a principle in programming that you separate your input-reading code from the rest of the program logic.  It just makes things easier to understand.  For some programs this is hard to do, but not yours.  I suggest rewriting your code like so...

```
int main() 
{
  // First read in values from the user.
  int val1, val2, val3;
  cout << "Enter three values\n";
  cout << "Enter the first value\n";
  cin >> val1;
  cout << "Enter the second value\n";
  cin >> val2;
  cout << "Enter the third value\n";
  cin >> val3;
  // You could add a logging statement here to verify your input code is working.

  // Now print val1, val2, val3 in consecutive order
  // Rest of the code goes here.
```

Structuring code like this makes I/O problems much easier to find.  Missing `cin >> val3` would be obvious with the above code layout.

Comment: `int high` is not the same as `int high = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are messed up with two things, one is the algorithm, and the other is the use of the language. Algorithm is the way you need to do it, and use of language is how well you use the tools in the language to express yourself. Now what you want to do is clear, but the first thing you are messed up with is using `if`. You have used all `if`s, which is done when your conditions are independent of each other, like you want to check if two conditions are true, you print "YES" twice. Example:

```
if(/*condition 1*/)
    cout<<"YES\n";
if(/*condition 2*/)
    cout<<"YES\n";
```

In your problem, either a number can be greater, or smaller, or less. Implementing your code the way I'll write will be much easy for you to read, and write.

```
 #include "../../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int maximum(int a, int b){
    if(a>b)
        return a;
    return b;
}

int minimum(int a, int b){
    if(a<b)
        return a;
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    int val1, val2, val3;
    cout << "Enter three values you bastard1\n";
    cout << "Enter the first value\n";
    cin >> val1;
    cout << "Enter the second value\n";
    cin >> val2;
    cout << "Enter the third value\n";
    cin>> val3;
    cout<<"The numbers in order are:\n";
    int a,b,c;
    a = minimum(val1 , minimum(val2,val3));
    c = maximum(val1 , maximum(val2,val3));
    b = val1 + val2 + val3 - a - c;
    cout<< a << " " << b << " " <<c<<"\n";
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers,This is the end piece.It is functioning. its only issue seems to be that is repeating the last IF statement after it has sequenced the numbers except only in the occasion that the statement comes true. (when val3 is greater than the lowest value but smaller than the highest.

```
#include "../../../std_lib_facilities.h"
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter three values\n";
    cout << "Enter the first value\n";
    int val1 = 0;
    int high = 0;
    int low = 0;
    cin >> val1;
    cout << "Enter the second value\n";
    int val2 = 0;
    cin >> val2;
    high = (val1 >= val2) ? val1 : val2;
    low = (val1 <= val2) ? val1 : val2;
    cout << "Enter the third value\n";
    int val3 = 0;
    cin >> val3;
    if (val3 >= high)
    {
        cout << low << " " << high << " " << val3;
    }
    if (val3 <= low)
    {
        cout << val3 << " " << low << " " << high;
    }
    if (low<val3<high)
    {
        cout << low <<" "<< val3<<" " << high;
    }

    cout << endl;
    return 0;

}
```